# Docker unable to start, new network adapter created on every restart

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I am using Docker 1.8.2c, VirtualBox 5.0.4 on Windows 8.1.

I have been successfully been using this configuration for a long period, but then I had to install OpenShift to check its feasibility. This never worked out as there were networking issues with new network adapters being created all the time, and not being able to connect to the internet.

I have uninstalled everything, and reinstalled Docker 1.8.2c and somehow the problem is still persistent and Docker will not even start now.

I have looked around and not found a way to investigate or resolve the problem.

Thanks for your advice.

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a more recent Docker? 1.8 is over a year and a half old and they've fixed many bugs since.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do an upgrade like Dan Lowe said and if you have error messages can you post them here ?